# Website same view on other devices

Tags: html, viewport, meta

How can I make my website have the same view even if it's viewed from a smartphone, tablet or PC? I have a table on the webpage. I've tried this but has no effect:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your declaration is saying to size the web page to the width of the device, which it doesn't seem like you want. You actually want the opposite of this if you want it to show up on mobile similar to on desktop. Try setting a fixed viewport size, so that the website will not take screen size into account on mobile devices:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">
```

Comment: It's a little bit of change but not that much

Comment: @Ann If you want a greater change, try setting width to something wider, like 1920.

Comment: Just did that but it looks the same. Can i somehow zoom out or so?

Comment: @Ann It's possible that your table is being sized in `em` or another unit that is affected differently by the viewport size. Make sure the table and its fonts are sized in pixels, then if you're still having issues please try to recreate your problem in a jsFiddle. Thanks!

Comment: @Ann In your JSFiddle, you have the meta viewport tag specified twice in the `head`, so the second one is overriding the first one. I also added `initial-scale=0.25` to the tag so that the page starts zoomed out on mobile. Here is the [final working version of your page](http://numberless-point.surge.sh/).

Comment: That worked ! Thank you ! If you could help me with one last thing, the background image keeps on duplicating till the bottom of the page

Comment: @Ann You probably want `background-repeat: repeat-x;` or `background-repeat: no-repeat;`. More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat